# Does Xcode not have the ability to dock windows and organise the IDE a bit better?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I find myself having to go Window>Console each time, is there not a better way of handling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Xcode preferences (COMMAND+COMMA), under "Debugging", you can click on the "On Start:" drop-down menu and select "Show Console & Debugger"  to automatically show it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just use Cmd-shift-R. Works well enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may also like the alternate "All-In-One" project arrangement - close out any open projects, go into XCode preferences, select the first tab (General).  In the dropdown, select "All-In-One"

Now when you start the debugger, the debugger and stack review and console will all be gathered into one window.